# Fixed points of a system of differential equiations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Given is the following differential equation $$x'=y\\ y'=-2x-4\epsilon x^3
 $$ with $\epsilon \geq 0$.

I was asked to calculate the fixed points, so I found that $y=0$ and for $-2x-4\epsilon x^3=0$, I found $x=0$ or $x=\pm \sqrt\frac{1}{2\epsilon} i$.

I know that $(0,0)$ is a fixed point, but I don't know what to do with these complex solutions for $x$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For each $\epsilon>0$, there is only fixed point, which is the one you found at $(0,0)$.

Comment: So the complex solution for $x$ can be ignored? Why is that?

Comment: What is the context in which this DE arose? Do $x$ and $y$ represent something physical, like in a model? Or is the DE purely of mathematical interest?

Comment: Indeed, $x$ and $y$ are functions of the real time $t$, both with values in the real line.

Comment: Purely of mathematical interest!